# busybox ntpd does not resync date/time after changing it

Tags: ntp, busybox, ntpd

I'm trying to figure out how ntpd (from busybox) works.
I'm running the following scenario, for a test sake:

1. set up date/time, using `date -s`, to any arbitrary date/time (e.g. `2000-01-01 00:00:00`);
2. run the command `ntpd -N -p <server_address>` to start the daemon. Just after that, the date/time is successfully sync;
3. change the date/time againt, using `date -s`, to the same used in the 1st step (i.e. `2000-01-01 00:00:00`);

After that, I have been expecting that date/time was synchronized again, but this doesn't occur, even if I wait for a couple of hours.

My question is: my comprehension about the ntpd's behavior is correct? Should the date/time be resync automatically after the 3rd step? If not, what should I do to resync the date/time?

Comment: That's outside of the allowed correction window of 1000 sec (From memory). Try a smaller change and see if that behaves as expected. The 1st sync is prob called with the `-g` or equivalent flag but then ntp expects to keep the clock in check within 500PPM hence no 3rd correction.

Comment: @user3788685 I'd tried a smaller change (about 5min) and I've waited for a couple of hours again, but the time wasn't resynced.

Comment: Can you show the output from `ntpq -pcrv` presuming the busybox version supports that full command. We need to see the state of ntp while its running normal, and once you change the time.

Comment: @user3788685 Unfortunately my embedded system doesn't support this call.

Answer (score 1):

I would check internaly in the trimmed [busybox implementation](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/ntpd.c#n2277) if the use case is actually covered. Some options could be actually ignored and that can cause confusion.

If not, in case it is a yocto based embedded system, you should consider [bring the actual and complete ntpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486985/replace-busybox-ntpd-with-ntp-from-meta-openembedded) instead of the busybox one.