# Replace busybox ntpd with ntp from meta-openembedded

Tags: yocto, ntp, busybox

I would like to replace the standard `ntpd` that comes with `busybox` with the full NTP server released in [meta-openembedded](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/ntp?h=morty).
However, I can't find the configuration or Yocto variable that sets that this version of the busybox should not have `ntpd`.

What is the efficient way to do this? Keep in mind that I can't edit the released Poky layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved is quite simple.
There was a file in my layer called `busybox/files/ntpd.cfg` with a flag `CONFIG_NTPD`. I've just set it to `n` and busybox was without ntpd.

Comment: Is there also a way to set this variable in a separate recipe so that you don't have to adjust busybox inside the `meta`-layer?

Answer (score 1):

I have in fact done the same to have the complete version of wget. There are 2 steps:

1. Configure busybox so that it does not provide such executable.
2. Include the [recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/ntp?h=morty) you located in your build.

For the first point the most elegant way is to crate a layer with its bbappend for busybox. You can follow [the official example](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/tree/master/meta-skeleton/recipes-core/busybox). I would initially check the [default configuration](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox/defconfig). You can go faster by doing it manually like explained [here](https://community.nxp.com/thread/314980). Either if you create a fragment for your bbappend or you do it manually through the `bitbake -c menuconfig busybox`. You can check in the sorce code what is the [configuration entries](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/ntpd.c#n43) that need to be modified.

The second is the easiest part,  install ntp recipe either via image recipe or in your local.conf. (IMAGE_INSTALL or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL variables respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "ntp" or PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "ntp" to your local.conf.